# i want to copy all fields of standard object into custom object how to do this? std object:opportunity custom object:Opportunity_clone__cc

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger CloneOpp on Opportunity( after insert, after update ) {
  Set<String> fields = Opportunity.getSobjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet();
  Map<Id,opportunity_clone__c> co2 = new Map<Id,Opportunity_clone__c>();
  for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
    co2.put(record.opportunity_clone__c,new opportunity_clone__c(id=record.opportunity_clone__c));
    for(String field:fields) {
      if(field.indexOf('__c')>-1) { // This is a custom field.
        try {
          Opportunity_clone__c.getSobject(record.opportunity_clone__c).put(field,record.get(field));
        } catch(exception e) { /* NOTE: This just means copy failed. */ }
      }
    }
  }
  update co2.values();
}
```

Comment: Do you get any failures?

Comment: Variable does not exist: opportunity_clone__c getting this error

Comment: Try to edit your question and please be more specific please.

Comment: My requirement is copy all fields from standard object to custom object using trigger (dynamically) not using field names directly

Comment: you can use clone() method of sObject class.. 
[sObject class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) search for clone method

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with your trigger code, I am able to come up with a solution which work only on After insert.

It only copies the custom fields of opportunity into custom object. 
It assumes that the custom object have similar field api name as standard object has.

System audit fields can not be edited easily. There is a way to do that but is out of the scope of this question.

I haven't tested it myself. So give it a try.

```
trigger CloneOpp on Opportunity( after insert){
    Set<String> fields = Opportunity.getSobjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet();
    List<opportunity_clone__c> co2 = new List<Opportunity_clone__c>();
    for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
        opportunity_clone__c clone = new opportunity_clone__c();
        for(String field:fields) {
            //This will only copy custom fields of opportunity and assumes that field api name is similar in custom object
            if(field.indexOf('__c')>-1){
                clone.put(field, record.get(field));
            }else if(field.equalsIgnoreCase('Name')){
                clone.put(field, record.get(field));
            }
            //mention other standard fields similarly, system fields such as Id, createdDate etc can not be copied. 
        }
        co2.add(clone);
    }
    insert co2;
}
```